# In a generic manner, how to find the Freebase property that holds a user readable name for an arbitrary type

Tags: types, properties, freebase

If I have a type, such as "/government/government_position_held", how do I determine which of its properties holds the user readable name? In this case it is the property "office_position_or_title".  In the case of "/sports/sports_played", the property is "sport".  In the case of "/film/performance", the property is "film".  Some types have a "name" property, but many do not.  I'd need a generic means of doing this, rather than having to know the specific schema for each type.

Answer (score 0):

Most types have names.  The main exceptions are the so-called "mediator" types or "compound value types" (ie CVTs).  CVTs typically have no name (ie the /type/object/name property has a null value).  If there only two non-primitive named types connected to the CVT (ie the others are things like dates, currencies, etc), you may be able to distinguish the "best" name by the direction that you're coming from (ie it's the other named type).  But for something like your `/film/performance` example, who says that the "best" property is `/film/performance/film` rather than `/film/performance/character`?  Or, alternatively, if I started at the film, why wouldn't it be `/film/performance/actor`?

That's the whole point of mediators/CVTs.  They sit between/among all the other nodes.  You might be able to codify an algorithm to deal with the simple case (ie two linked named non-primitive types), but the general case is hard.

Comment: Hi Tom, thanks for the insight - so, the /film/actor type has a property /film/actor/film, and this has an expected_type of /film/performance.  I'm trying to figure out which property in the /film/performance type I should look at to get the readable name.  In this case it's coincidence that the property on /film/actor is "film", and that happens to be the name of the property on /film/performance I want.  But this isn't always the case, as you mention.  The master property for the /film/actor/film property is /film/performance/actor, which doesn't help much in this case.

Comment: My main point is that the mediator type or CVT /film/performance has no name.  You can construct an effective name by going one hop further if you know a) the direction you're coming from and b) the most desirable destination, if there are multiple.  Some apps would think if you started from actor that the "correct" answer is "film," while others might thing it's "character."  That's an intrinsic nature of non-binary relationships that you'll need to deal with in an application-specific manner.

Comment: I'm finding the need to build a map that has the following:

Comment: I'm finding the need to build a map that has the following:  if type is /film/actor and prop is /film/actor/film, then use the film property in /film/performance.  if type is /film/film and prop is /film/film/starring then use the actor property in /film/performance.  If type is /film/film_character and prop is /film/film_character/portrayed_in_films, then use the film property in /film/performance.  In other words, for each property pointing to an expected type, there's a logical property of the expected type to use for the name.  I'd like to derive an automated means of building this mapping